# getUserMedia silently fails on user declining permission to use microphone in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, getusermedia

Doesn't Firefox fire an error when the user declines the usage of the microphone when getUserMedia is called? This code will not log an error in Firefox, but does in Chrome.

This is the code I am using:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.
    getUserMedia(media).
    then(function(stream) {
        // doing some stuff here
    }).
    catch(function(error) {
        // log errors
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Anything I am missing?

**EDIT:** I just found out that if I click "Not now" in the permission dialog, no error is fired. If I click "Never for this website", the error is fired, But this behavior is far from being ideal as I have no chance to inform the user in case he (accidently) clicks "Not now" instead of granting the permission.

Comment: This is a [common misunderstanding](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1004055#c0). [Firefox Beta](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/) has [brand new permission prompts](http://www.ghacks.net/2017/01/19/firefox-permission-system/) without this UX flaw. They're near-modal but should satisfy your specific concern.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it fires on firefox.

But this is by the design when the user clicks 'Not Now' the request is still active; the user still can allow access to media devices by clicking on URL pane icons on the right side. Hence you don't get any feedback. 
Yes, on chrome you get an error but not on firefox.

> You need to use **timers** to detect such scenario(hackish).

for more info, refer this thread:https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=947266

[image]

> If the user provides permission, then the returned Promise is resolved with the resulting MediaStream object. If the user denies permission, or media is not available, then the promise is rejected with **PermissionDeniedError** or **NotFoundError** respectively.

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true }).then(function(stream) {
  /* use the stream */
}).catch(function(err) {
  alert(err)
});
```

Comment: Well, what can I say. It does not for me where all other browsers are.

Comment: When I click "not now" then no error is shown. Do I click "Never" then the error shows. But that behavior is not ideal.

Comment: @ArminHierstetter yes you are right. I have explained this case. Also you can refer to the provided link for more information regarding this case

Comment: Thanks for that. Still think that Firefox should change the way it handles this. The current behavior does not make sense, I feel.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to use `focus` event to `throw` an `Error`, or pass `Error` to `Promise.reject()` with `.catch()` chained to same error handling function if `stream` is not defined when `window` regains focus

```
   let stream;
   let handleError = error => {
     // log errors
     alert(error);
   }
   let getMediaPermission = new Promise(resolve => {          
      if ("MozAnimation" in document.body.style) {
        this.onfocus = () => {
          this.onfocus = null;
          if (!stream) Promise.reject(new Error("stream not defined"))
                       .catch(handleError)
        }
      }
      resolve(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true}));
    });
    getMediaPermission
    .then(stream => {
      stream = stream;
      console.log(stream)
     // doing some stuff here
    })
    .catch(handleError);
```

Comment: Awesome hack! Thanks for that. Still think that Firefox should change the way it handles this.